# split one pandas column text to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have one pandas column contain

```
text
A1V2
B2C7Z1
```

I want split it into 26(A-Z) columns with alphabet followed value, if it is missing, then -1.

So, it can be

```
text    A  B  C  D ...  Z
A1V2    1  -1 -1 -1 ... -1
B2C7Z1 -1  2  7  -1 ... 1
```

Is there any fast way rather than using df.apply()?

**Followup:**
Thank Psidom for the brilliant answer. When I use the method run 4 millions rows, it took me 1 hour. I hope there's another way can make it faster. It seems str.extractall() is the most time-consuming one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `str.extractall` with regex `(?P<key>[A-Z])(?P<value>[0-9]+)` which extracts the key(*[A-Z]*) value(*[0-9]+*) into separate columns and a long to wide transform should get you there.

Here regex `(?P<key>[A-Z])(?P<value>[0-9]+)` matches *letterDigits* pattern and the two capture groups go into two separate columns in the result as columns *key* and *value* (with `?P<>` syntax);

And since *extractall* puts multiple matches into separate rows, you will need to transform it to wide format with `unstack` on the `key` column:

```
(df.text.str.extractall("(?P<key>[A-Z])(?P<value>[0-9]+)")
 .reset_index('match', drop=True)
 .set_index('key', append=True)
 .value.unstack('key').fillna(-1))

#key    A   B   C   V   Z
#  0    1  -1  -1   2  -1
#  1   -1   2   7  -1   1
```

Comment: That is smart !

Comment: I found this took me 1 hour to run 4 million rows. Is there any faster way?

Comment: It's not surprising if it takes a long time, and there's not particularly a better way for the data extraction method I can think of. However you can consider splitting data frame into chunks and utilize [parallel processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to speed things up.